# Updated: Free tools for checking security vulnerabilities for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, security-testing

I would like to know whether there are any free tools available which can be used to test security vulnerabilities in a rails app. I came across [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/), which I found was not very intuitive in its report. Are there any similar tools available?

**Update**

I've found a tool, [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project), which can be used for doing penetration testing for any Web applications. You can easily automate it by integrating it with testing tools such as Selenium. This looks really cool and has many features and easy to use too.

Leena

Answer (score 4):

Rails Best Practices already mentioned is very good for general code quality checks, but specifically for security vulnerabilities checks, definitely have a look at [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/), "an open source vulnerability scanner specifically designed for Ruby on Rails applications. It statically analyzes Rails application code to find security issues at any stage of development".

You could also hook your app in to [Rails Brakeman](http://rails-brakeman.com/) to have the Brakeman security report run every time you do a commit at Github.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/) looks interesting. Will check that for sure.

Comment: There's also the brakeman [jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/brakeman-plugin) as well as [guard-brakeman](https://github.com/guard/guard-brakeman) ;)

Comment: I suggest also giving [codesake-dawn](https://github.com/codesake/codesake-dawn) a try. Codesake::Dawn is a security source code scanner with more than 140 security checks, It's similiar do brakeman and it supports also Sinatra and Padrino frameworks. Disclaimer: I'm Codesake::Dawn author... it would be great to me having some feedback to improve the tool even more.

Answer (score 1):

I can see only the book about it [Rails Security Guides](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Ruby_on_Rails_Security_Guide_V2)

To overall check your code use [rails_best_practices gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for some tools which can be used for doing security testing as part of our build process.